# Image causes Application to crash

Tags: android, image, android-activity, device, imagebutton

i have an activity that loads 6 pictures into ImageButton and each of the picture is about 150kb and one about 250kb.

why do my application always crash when it tries to load into this page on device? there were no problem loading it in emulator.

i tried removing the images and then the application work just fine. is it size issue?

Comment: And what does the stack trace say ?

Comment: Yes please share your logcat.

Comment: how do i use that on device? adb? im a beginner in android.

Answer (score 0):

Check **naming pattern** of your images that you are using

Should Not use Capital character in the name

**Example** Test = test

Should Not Use Desh in the name

**Example** te-st = te_st

Sholud Not use numbers in the name

**Example** test1 = test_one

Check these type of mistakes in your pictures name.